# TFS 2010 - Adding users to a Team Project

Tags: active-directory, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Tried searching the archives, but nothing showed up and now I'm totally messed up in my head.

I'm running my own little domain setup on a virtual server:

- Server 1, PDC, Exchange
- Server 2, SQL
- Server 3, IIS, TFS 2010 and some other misc stuff

Now I'm connection from my dekstop computer which is not connected to the domain, but I can still use the TFS and other services when I'm not joined to the domain, which is kind a nice, since I'm in a other location most of the time.

Now I have a friend that I want to host a Team Project for ... I can create it via Visual Studio 2010 ... BUT ... how do I set the permissions to a domain users when my desktop machine is not a member of the domain?

I can't even find an option in the "Team Foundation Server Administration Console" on the server ... there I can only find options to set global security settings, but not on the on a single "Team Project"

I have also tried from the tfs web interface ... no luck there either.

Can it really be true that its only possible from a machine that is joined to the domain?

Just blogged about the solution at: [Adding users to a TFS Project from the server.](http://ifyoudo.net/post/2010/10/09/Adding-users-to-a-TFS-Project-from-the-server.aspx)

mvh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can actually be done from the server.

- Open the "Team Foundation Server Administration Console"
- In the left pane, go to "Server -> Application Tier -> Team project collections"
- The tab "General"
- Group membership"
- Select the "[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Valid Users"
- Here you can see all the projects and groups ...

This is the most odd way ... but is was there :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use remote desktop on to server 3.

But simpler might be from within VS with Team Explorer. Right click on the project node and under Team Project Settings there is Group Settings. From here you can add/remove group members.

This assumes the domain account you are using to connect to TFS has sufficient TFS permissions to modify the relevant groups.

[This is based on TFS2005 & 2008, but I understand this has not changed to 2010.]

Comment: My account has all the permissions that is needed, I created the "Team project" from VS. The problem is that I can't add users from the domain, which is what I want. How can I do it from "Server 3" running the TFS Service? I dont see where I can select the project and then add users ... I can only do it on a global level, not on projects, ( or if I can, I havent found it yet )

Comment: @Syska The TFS installed also installs VS Shell + Team Explorer. So on the TFS server you can also manipulate all TFS settings. (On your machine the lack of domain membership will make adding domain members header, this shouldn't be a problem on the TFS server.) Use View | Team Explorer to see the list of projects (and from there right click on the root node to connect to projects) to get per-project options.

Comment: I have no VS Shell or Team Explorer on the server. The only tool I can find is the "Team Foundation Server Administration Console". I not sure I understand the last part ... "Use view | Team Explorer". I can see a list in the "Team Foundation Server Administration Console" under the tab "Team Projects", but the only option I get there is to delete projects and a MSDN link on how to add team projects". This crap is freaking me out ...

Comment: @Syska: Looks like TFS2010 has changed that then. (The instructions were for using VS Shell/Team Explorer). Summary: You need an instance of VS + Team Explorer running on a domain member.

Comment: I'm afaid so, but I will keep this question open for a few more days if someone should know of a way ... so I can avoid joining a computer to the domain, or else I could create a virtual machine and use that. Just seems so odd that its not possible without. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for adding users to TFS 2010 when your development machine doesn't have access to the remote domain.

Create the user on the server if you haven't already done so and Add the user to the ProjectTeam group.

Then on your local machine that isn't tied to the domain, simply create a user with the same username.

Right-Click on your project in Team Explorer and choose "Team Project Settings" --> "Group Membership..."

Click on the group you want to add the user to, and press the "Properties" button.

Select "Windows User or Group" and click "Add"...then just type in the username (you shouldn't need to specify the domain) - even if it initially identifies your current computer/domain...it should automatically change it to the remote domain.

Then you can delete that username from your local computer.

I spent about 4 hours trying to add a user for a remote domain before getting this to work. Microsoft really should have thought about this scenario for remote developers, TFS running on remotely hosted servers and so on.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I will try it when I get home ... just for the fun of it, since I have allready set of a virtual computer, just for the sake of adding users. I will mark this answer as the right if it works ( witch sounds like it does, but hell on earth, MS should have thought about this )

Comment: Actually, I found how to do it from the TF Server Administration Console in 2010. See my original post.

Comment: See my own answer.